# Server command via AJAX interface

Tags: ajax, interface

I'm new on AJAX. Just for fun I'm trying to control my sever via an AJAX interface.
It's quite easy, for instance in PHP, to send a command to the server by the system() function and just a text field and a submit button.

The thing I'd like to do is to control in realtime some action, for example controlling music volume by a web interface, with a simple slide without any submit button.

Don't care about the way to control volume, is just a piece of example, imagine it like a php system() function.

WELL the question is:
How can I implement such a remote control system**?** (The server is the machine that in this single case hosts the webserver).

Comment: SECURITY! Please make sure you sanitize all your inputs!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I am tempted to -1 this because the question is so unclear. What server? There's no single thing in the world called Ajax. If you don't post a full description, no one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to do the control with a PHP only webinterface (e.g. reading requests like http://server/control.php?volume=10 or http://server/control.php?jumpToPercent=30)?

From there you can Ajaxify it partially e.g. by sending your form submits asynchronously via Ajax (recommending the [jQuery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin). If you want to use a slider you could use the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/), which sends a request like

```
$.getJSON('http://server/control.php', { jumpToPercent : $(slider).percentValue() },
    function(data) { $(slider).value(data.value); }, 'json');
```

whenever it is changed (read the documentation for the correct events and invocations) and your PHP script changes the position and returns e.g.

```
{ "value" : 50 }
```

which is the new actual position of the slider.